# cplex (default) cannot extract expression

Tags: cplex

I have a question as follows: after finishing coding the MIP math model, I tested it with data with 63,782 constraints, 41,262 binary, 12 integer, and 6,709,862 non-zero coefficients. It can produce optimal results, and there aren't any errors at all. However, when I run with larger data, the error "cplex (default) cannot extract expression" appears for some constraints in my model.

Please help me explain whether my model has an error, is out of memory, or has any other reason. Thank you!